# Converting 16 bit audio sample to char

Tags: python, c++, casting, alsa

I am using matrix creator board and I am trying to make a python wrapper for their mic array C++ code.

The library has a read function that returns a `uint16_t` array of 128 samples.

I'm trying to compare it to *ALSA* `readi` function that writes the buffer to a `char` array that the user passes as an argument to the function.

The question is how does *ALSA* write 16-bit samples to char array when single `char` is only 8 bit wide?
And how could I do the same with `uint16_t` array and pass it to python so I'll get the same result as with *ALSA* `readi` function?

Comment: Your 16-bit sample data is a sequence of 16-bit words. An array of `char` is a sequence of 8-bit words. An array of 128 16-bit words is equal to an array of 256 8-bit words. There's no "conversion" going on, just copying from one array to another.

Comment: You could use `memcpy`

Comment: I used memcpy but now the problem is when I return the char array to python and convert it from char pointer to string the length changes so now sometimes the length of the string is less than 256 chars and it jumps between 0 and 70

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A uint16 can be passed as 2 bytes (uint8), the c++ code probably uses a union so that the data can be saved as a uint16 while the USB code can pass the data as bytes.

As for the python code, this is the function I use to convert 8-bit bytes to uint16

```
def convert_int8_int16(self, byte_array):
    new_array = [0]*(len(byte_array)/2)
    for i in range(len(byte_array)/2):
        new_array[i] = byte_array.pop(0)*256 + byte_array.pop(0)

    return new_array
```

This will go through the byte array and add the values to a new uint16 array.